# How do I add a menu extra to the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

From the terminal window I frequent run this command to strip formatting from copied text.

```
pbpaste|pbcopy
```

How can I wrap this up in something so I can have a menu button to click that will do the same thing?